# Conditional Ternary Operator React.js, Javascript (Data Structures)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on this [React.js Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and had a question on this code here: [Codepen.](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/WZpxpz?editors=0010)

I have been confused with the conditional ternary operator that's used. Here it's below:

```
const fahrenheit = scale === 'c' ? tryConvert(temperature, toFahrenheit) : temperature;

const celsius = scale === 'f' ? tryConvert(temperature, toCelsius) : temperature;
```

From my understanding, the way that this line of code works is like below:

```
if (scale === "f") {
  const celsius = tryConvert(temperature, toCelsius);
} else 
  return temperature;
}

if (scale === "c") {
  const fahrenheit = tryConvert(temperature, toFahrenheit);
} else 
  return temperature;
}
```

As you will notice on the Codepen site that once celsius is altered, fahrenheit is also changed at that very moment. My understanding of the code suggests that if the scale that's being altered is equal to "c" then convert the temperature to fahrenheit else don't modify the temperature value.

I tried to delete the original const fahrenheit and write it as a simple if else statement, like I have above, but it doesn't work.

Can someone help me identify where the fault is in the if else statement that I wrote? I want to understand the conditional ternary operator as an if else statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your `if`/`else` block to function similarly to your ternary as shown in the example above, you must do this.

```js
render() {
    const scale = this.state.scale;
    const temperature = this.state.temperature;
    
    // This assignment effectively covers the else part in the ternary.
    let celsius = temperature;
    let fahrenheit = temperature;
    
    if(scale === 'f') {
        celcius = tryConvert(temperature, toCelsius);
    }
    if(scale === 'c') {
        fahrenheit = tryConvert(temperature, toFahrenheit);
    }
    
    return (
    // do stuff
```

Comment: Uh, you do realize that farenheight is a global or undeclared variable referencing the highest enclosing scope here right?  This is not a good example.

Comment: @user120242 what do you mean? `fahrenheit` in the code block is within the scope of the `render()` method.

Comment: No it isn't.  farenheight has not been declared.  That is an assignment statement.  Add `setTimeout(()=>console.log(farenheight),5000)` somewhere else in the code.  It will retrieve the value set by the render function.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/93j6Luqa/1/  as said: `fahrenheit` has not been properly declared or scoped

Comment: @user120242 I just got around to test it and you are correct about the scope. I was unaware of shorthand assignment putting successive variable names in global scope. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the "simple" if else statement you have here is that the variables are declared with "const" which makes them local to the scope of the block (delimited by curly braces). Also `return` statement will stop the execution of the function if it's in a function, it doesn't make sense to `return` outside of a function.

What you could do is take the declaration outside before the conditions :

```
let celsius, fahrenheit;
if (scale === "f") {
  celsius = tryConvert(temperature, toCelsius);
} else 
  celsius = temperature;
}

if (scale === "c") {
  fahrenheit = tryConvert(temperature, toFahrenheit);
} else 
  fahrenheit = temperature;
}
```

now this is what the ternary form can be translated to.

Comment: If you run that same code in Codepen by replacing it with the ternary form it doesn't work... I don't think the const relates to the "scope" given that the celsius variable is being passed around as a props.

Comment: Declaring a variable as a const has nothing to do with the scope, but rather the mutability of it. The placement of the variable determines the scope.

Comment: @Bren it does when compared to var : https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/#:~:text=var%20variables%20can%20be%20updated,const%20variables%20are%20not%20initialized.

Comment: @KiJéy Incorrect. See this example: https://codepen.io/brenr/pen/vYLQooa

Comment: @Bren Wow you really want to prove that I'm wrong don't you ? Yes functions create a scope of their own whether you use var or const/let but that's not the case for any other code block surrounded with curly braces. See : https://codepen.io/Mouradif/pen/QWyzdZm

Comment: @KiJéyI think you're taking this the wrong way. When someone reading sees that const is scoped which is correct, it could be misinterpreted which was what I was pointing out. It never occurred to me that const was scoped because it would never make sense to make a declaration in any conditional and any good linter *should* catch that. I think we're on the same page though lol.

Comment: Take OP's question, replace const with var, it works. Why ? Because const is scoped. I don't see what's confusing about this